# magento 2 cannot do shipment for the order 404

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping, magento-2.1.9

In Magento 2 - I'm trying to change the order from processing to shipped, I seem to have no problem doing this in chrome, however when I hit the ship button I get the following error:

[image]

Its IE11 so its not a super old browser but it keeps happening, I can't find any error logs for it and I'm pretty stumped.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there a fix for it?

Comment: See this [questions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136139/shipping-failure-404-or-400-on-magento-2), this might help

Comment: Nope, that link didn't help :(

Comment: Having the same problem, did you solve this?

Comment: User permissions, I mean what the user can see in the backend. And upgraded to 2.2.X

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @andyjones which permissions did you change to fix it? I already running 2.2.5 and getting the exact same thing on a restricted user.

Comment: I changed the logged in user permissions, not file permissions. You need to make sure the user has the correct access in the backend.

Comment: @andyjones thanks for the reply.  I had assumed you meant user permissions. My question was meant to ask which permissions did you change to solve the problem. I’ve already given the user everything normal but I wondered which extra functionality you’d enabled in the user role.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to the site anymore. So I wouldn't be able to tell you which ones it was. My advice, enable them all and work backwards.

Comment: Are you fixed this issue?

Comment: I also facing the same issue

Comment: Same problem here, anybody found a fix

Comment: Does anyone get a solution for this??

Comment: Also encountering this issue.

Comment: Anybody ever found a solution, we still sometimes have this issue, it does not really matter because the shipment is created but it would be nice to get this solved. Still have it on 2.3.4